# Expand-Archive failing with type failure in Powershell 7

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell 7 script that includes a call to Expand-Archive to extract a ZIP archive to a particular location. This call worked when the script ran in earlier versions of Powershell.

During a recent effort to "level up" our scripts to Powershell 7.x, we ran this same script and encountered this error:

```
InvalidOperation: Unable to find type [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]
```

Initial research suggested I needed to call 'add-type' to explicitly add the ZipFileExtensions type from the System.IO.Compression.Zipfile assembly, but this also generated an "InvalidOperation" error. Attempts to expliclity instantiate the type similarly failed.

I then dug in a bit further and discovered that, apparently, the ZipFileExtensions type is actually a .NET **Framework** type, not a .NET **Core** type, which explains the InvalidOperation errors. However, I've seen no indication that Expand-Archive should not or cannot be used within Powershell 7.x, so I have to infer there's some step I'm just overlooking, or perhaps some .NET Core assembly I need that could be missing from the target device. That's speculation.

As a stop-gap, I can run the expand within a "Windows Powershell" Script-Block, and it works, but given part of this effort was to level up our scripts to Powershell 7.x, this is hardly an ideal solution. I'm hoping there's a better solution.

How do I overcome this issue in Powershell 7?

EDIT: In response to the request for Get-Command Expand-Archive, I add the following:

```
CommandType: Function
Name: Expand-Archive
Version 1.2.5
Source: Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `Get-Command Expand-Archive` to your question?

Comment: Question amended as requested.

Comment: I receive an InvalidOperation error.

Comment: "I then dug in a bit further" - can you elaborate on what diagnostic observations you've made to conclude it's failing to resolve the .NET Framework-version of the `ZipFileExtensions` type?

Comment: Sounds like you have another module that is conflicting with that function. What happens if you try starting a new `pwsh -NoProfile` and then `Expand-Archive` ?

Comment: The first reference I saw within Microsoft documentation was on a .NET Framework page, with its host assembly [System.IO.Compression.FileSystem], and add-type therein failed. As noted, add-type for what appears to be the .NET Core version also fails.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon That worked!! How can I resolve/identify the conflict? This all part of a stock OS install, little to nothing customized.

Comment: Well its hard to tell which module is causing the conflict but it is probably an old one, written for Windows PowerShell :) check in `$profile` and see if you're loading any modules there, otherwise you will need to load the modules you normally use, one by one and test each one until you see the exception from `Expand-Archive` again

Comment: That's a plan. Thank you very much for the assist.

Comment: The only module in this script is IISAdministration, and the profile files within $PROFILE are all empty or non-existent. The mystery deepens, so I am inferring there's some cmdlet in the script that is inducing a module load that causes the issue. AT least I have somewhere to dig. Thanks again.

Comment: what is, exactly, the command you are using?

Comment: @sirtao expand-archive, as stated

Comment: sorry, i was not clear. I did mean the FULL command statement, with parameters and all.

Comment: @sirtao expand-archive -Path "\\sharepath\file.zip" -DestinationPath "localpath" -Force (Note: actual paths omitted)